# Update database using a loop on Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do a for each loop to update my database. I was using this piece of code to make the update:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    @t_id = params[:t_id]
    @t_order = params[:order]
    @t_relation = TRelation.where('t_id' => @t_id)
    @i = 0;
    @t_order.each do |p|
      @t_relation = TRelation.where('t_id = ? and
        video_id = ?', @t_id, p[1][@i])
      @i = @i + 1
      @t_relation[0].t_order = @i
      @t_relation[0].save
    end
    format.json { render :nothing => true, :status => 200, :content_type => 'text/html' }
  end
end
```

It does not loop through; it goes through it one time and stops. I don't understand what's happening.

This is the content of params[:order]

```
params[:order] = {ActionController::Parameters} ActionController::Parameters (1 element)
 '0' = Array (3 elements)
  [0] = "7"
  [1] = "5"
  [2] = "3"
```

And if I make a `@timeline_order.inspect` I get this:

```
{"0"=>["7", "5", "3"]}
```

How can I loop through it? I have no idea

Comment: ```@t_order["0"].each``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It iterates once because `params[:order]` only has one element. What you want to do is iterate on `@t_order["0"]`, which has 3 elements.

Also, you should avoid all that logic within the `respond_to`. You can (should) define the variables outside of it.